# Generating Qt pro files from sln file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-extensions

I like to make Qt applications in Visual Studio. But sometimes, there is a need to continue development in Linux space, where Visual Studio is not available. Therefore, there's a need to write down project files manually.

Is it possible to generate `.pro` files and `makefile`s from configurated `.sln` file?

Comment: How about CMake? There is a tool for conversion from sln to cmake: https://github.com/algorys/cmakeconverter

Comment: Since you already work in cross-platform environment, why really not consider *true* cross-platform solution like cmake, instead of workarounds with conversion :)

Comment: With Qt, you normally go the other way - you author `.pro` file, and `qmake` can generate `vcproj` and `sln` files from it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Microsoft Visual Studio so I never had to deal with *.sln* files.

But actually, to generate your Qt environment from the command line in linux, you don't need the *.sln* file.
You just have to do as follows:

- Create your project directory, let's call it *MyQtProject*
- Copy inside your sources files (.h, .cpp)
- Then `cd MyQtProject` and run `qmake -project` : It will read your directory and create your *.pro* file (adding your headers and sources files, ...).
- You can edit the generated *MyQtProject.pro* file to add some specific instructions (for example`QT += widgets`)
- Then you just have to run `qmake MyQtProject.pro` to generate the *Makefile*.
- Finally run `make` to compile.

Of course, you can create a build directory inside *MyQtProject* and run `qmake ../MyQtProject.pro` and `make` from inside it in order to not pollute your project folder with the *moc* files and the *cmake* related files.

I hope it can help you and solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that the solution is divided into projects (some of them are shared libraries, some of them are executables). I store them in separate directories combined in a directory like following `{solution_dir}/src/{project_name}` to be organized. And I won't collect all the `.h` and `.cpp` ones into one dir.

Comment: Of course no, you don't have to mix _.h_ and _.cpp_ of separate projects. But if all the inner projects are used to build your solution, running `qmake -projet` from the _solution_dir_ will find your sources even through packages (and the hierarchy will be respected too) and generate the _solution.pro_ properly. On the other hand, if you want to build your inner projects separately, you can generate a _.pro_ file by project at least. Don't hesitate to tell me if I have misunderstood your problem, I will not let a bad solution in this case.